# Крестики-нолики 10 на 10

Tags: java, разработка-игр

Как написать функцию проверки isGameOver() 5ти одинаковых символов подряд? Т.е. игра должна заканчиваться, когда какой-то игрок набирает 5 нулей или 5 крестиков по горизонтали, вертикали или же диагонали.

```
package game;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Class1 {



    static int [] canvas = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                            0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,}; //начальный массив

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        boolean b;
        boolean isCurrentX = false;
        do {
            isCurrentX = !isCurrentX;
            drawCanvas();
            System.out.println("Ходит " + (isCurrentX ? "X" : "O"));
            int n = getNumber();
            canvas[n] = isCurrentX ? 1 : 2;
            b = !isGameOver(n);
            if (isDraw()){
                System.out.println("Draw");
                return;
            }
        } while (b);
        drawCanvas();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println("Победитель: " + (isCurrentX ? "X" : "O") + "!");
    }

    static int getNumber(){

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true){
            try {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
                if (n >= 0 && n < canvas.length && canvas[n]==0){
                    return n;
                }
                System.out.println("Выберите свободное поле и введите его порядковый номер");
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Пожалуйста, введите порядковый номер клетки");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean isGameOver(int n){

        //
        /*     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            0  |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8  |  9  |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            10 |  11 |  12 |  13 |  14 |  15 |  16 |  17 |  18 |  19 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            20 |  21 |  22 |  23 |  24 |  25 |  26 |  27 |  28 |  29 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            30 |  31 |  32 |  33 |  34 |  35 |  36 |  37 |  38 |  39 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            40 |  41 |  42 |  43 |  44 |  45 |  46 |  47 |  48 |  49 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            50 |  51 |  52 |  53 |  54 |  55 |  56 |  57 |  58 |  59 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            60 |  61 |  62 |  63 |  64 |  65 |  66 |  67 |  68 |  69 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            70 |  71 |  72 |  73 |  74 |  75 |  76 |  77 |  78 |  79 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            80 |  81 |  82 |  83 |  84 |  85 |  86 |  87 |  88 |  89 |
          _____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
            90 |  91 |  92 |  93 |  94 |  95 |  96 |  97 |  98 |  99 |
               |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
               */







        return false;
    }

    static void drawCanvas(){
        System.out.println("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |");
        for (int i = 0; i < canvas.length; i++) {
            if (i!=0){
                System.out.print("|");
                if (i%10==0) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|_____|");
                    System.out.println("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |");
                }
            }

            if (canvas[i]==0) {
                if(i<10) {
                    System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print("  " + i + " ");
                }
            }
  //          int f=0, g=0;
            if (canvas[i]==1) 
                {
                    System.out.print("  X  ");
                }
            if (canvas[i]==2) 
                {
                    System.out.print("  O  ");
                }
        }
        System.out.print("|");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |");

    }

    public static boolean isDraw() {
        for (int n : canvas) if (n==0) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ваши предположения? идеи?

Comment: а в чём разница с http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/626767/Проверка-победы-в-крестики-нолики-по-диагонали?rq=1 ?

Comment: @Nofate нуу, нужны 2 счетчика, думаю. и они каким-то образом должны понимать, что стоит 5 одинаковых символов подряд, а не просто было поставлено 5 значений. т.е. наверное они должны обнуляться в какой-то момент ходов. даже не знаю

Comment: Зачем создавать массив нулей, если `int` по дефолту получает 0?

Comment: @Flippy не знал

Comment: Ну так, наверное, следует сесть и сначала почитать книгу ) замените этот ужас на `static int[] canvas = new int[100];` и все, все нули

Comment: @Flippy спасибо) а это только для красоты и удобочитаемости кода или еще на чем-то отражается?

Comment: @pavel видимо ни в чем и надо закрывать

Comment: подождите закрывать, как проверку нормальную сделать?) а то я начал заниматься уже таким: `if(n%11==0)
     {
      if((canvas[0]==canvas[11])&&(canvas[0]==canvas[22])
        &&(canvas[0]==canvas[33])&&(canvas[0]==canvas[44])||
        (canvas[11]==canvas[22])&&(canvas[11]==canvas[33])
        &&(canvas[11]==canvas[44])&&(canvas[11]==canvas[55])
        )
       return true;`

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk я вам давал в в прошлом вашем вопросе ссылку на вопрос, в котором представлены решения. В них достаточно сменить константу/передаваемый параметр, который отвечает за размер поля, и всё будет работать. И опять-таки повторюсь, что всё это дело с дико длинными `if`-ами - это категорически плохое решение. Что вас не устраивает в ответах на тот вопрос?

Comment: Нормальная проверка делается с помощью циклов. А точнее с помощью "цикла циклов": во внешнем цикле перебираются направления проверки, во внутреннем - клетки конкретного направления, с счетчиком количества подряд идущих одинаковых символов.

Comment: @Regent в Вашем коде в консоли появляется только: "Winner: " и всё

Comment: @AlexanderVasilchuk возможно, вы плохо тестировали или адаптировали код. В моём ответе предоставлен пример, в котором выводится `Winner: x`. Это если взять и полностью скопировать и запустить представленный код.

Comment: @alexander-vasilchuk  Александр, только что ответил на похожий вопрос. Посмотрите, может быть, такой алгоритм подойдёт: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637000/java-%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8/637183#637183